# Creating sub-lists in the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this code:

```
binary = '011010'
binary = list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(binary)]*3)))

b=[]
for h in range(len(binary)):
    for i in range(len(binary[h])-1):
        c = binary[h][i:i+2]
        b.append(c)
```

where i get the result:

```
binary = ['011', '010']
b = ['01', '11', '01', '10']
```

And I would like to get an effect:

```
b = [['01', '11'], ['01', '10']]
```

So I would like to first take `binary[0]` and make a loop and then next `binary[1]` and add the results to list 'b', but in separate sub-lists. While in the above code, it saves the results one by one in the list 'b'.
How can this be done? Ideally, sub-lists should be creating in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with *nested list comprehension*:

```
b = [ [ binary[h][i:i+2] for i in range(len(binary[h])-1)]
      for h in range(len(binary))]
```

So here for every value `h` in `range(len(binary))` we construct a separate list, with the list comprehension `[ binary[h][i:i+2] for i in range(len(binary[h])-1)]`. This list comprehension will let a variable `i` iterate over `range(len(binary[h])-1)` and for every element, add `binary[h][i:i+2]` to the sublist.

That being said, we can improve the code, and iterate over the elements of binary directly:

```
b = [ [ subbin[i:i+2] for i in range(len(subbin)-1)]
      for subbin in binary]
```

So here for every `subbin` list in `binary`, we generate a sublist (again with list comprehension), this is the result of `[ subbin[i:i+2] for i in range(len(subbin)-1)]` so we generate a list of `subbin[i:i+2]`s for every `i` in `range(len(subbin)-1)`.

Comment: All in all, the solution seems obvious, but somehow I did not get it :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simple way

```
b=[]
for h in range(len(binary)):
    inner = []
    for i in range(len(binary[h])-1):
        c = binary[h][i:i+2]
        inner.append(c)
    b.append(inner)
```

Or you could use a list comprehension

```
b = [[binary[h][i:i+2] for i in range(len(binary[h])-1)] for h in range(len(binary)) ]
```